# How to get Cygwin terminal display output instantly after entering command?

Tags: c++, terminal, cygwin

I coded a simple c++ program:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main() {
    int q; scanf("%d", &q);
    while (q--) {
        int a, b;
        scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
        printf("%d\n", a+b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I execute the program on Cygwin terminal and type a query, it doesn't show   the output instantly (i.e I type "2 3" and the terminal should display the output "5" but it doesn't). It only displays outputs after I had typed all of the q queries.

The program still works interactively on Windows Command Prompt.

Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `fflush(stdout);`?

Comment: It works, thanks. But is there any other ways to do it without modifying the code ?

Comment: And why the program still runs interactively on Windows cmd?

Comment: different flush strategy of system libraries. [link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fflush.html)